# Как в java заменить обратный слеш двойным обратным слешем?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, java, mysql

Делаю так

```
path.replaceAll("\\", "\\\\");
```

Вываливает

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unexpected
internal error near index 1
\
 ^
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1713)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1466)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1133)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:823)
    at java.lang.String.replaceAll(String.java:2189)
    at ru.sersem.coreserver.MySqlConnector.createNewRepo(MySqlConnector.java:378)
    at ru.sersem.coreserver.GitSpider.createNewRepo(GitSpider.java:220)
    at ru.sersem.coreserver.ServerDispatcher.dispatchMessage(ServerDispatcher.java:56)
    at ru.sersem.coreserver.ClientListener.run(ClientListener.java:31)
```

Если так

```
path.replaceAll("u0431", "u0431 u0431");
```

то вообще ничего не происходит.
Это для вставки в mysql, может в запросе как-то можно сохранить слеши, а то в базу пишется все без слешей.

Comment: path.replaceAll("\\\","\\\\{2}")

Comment: здесь первый слеш экранирует строку до конца

Comment: Парсер сайта съел слэши :(в первых кавычках 2 слэша, во вторых 4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот так работает - `path.replaceAll("\\\\\\\\","\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\");`
P.S. Если передавать через `PreparedStatement` там разве всякие левые символы в строке не заэкранируются сами как надо?

Comment: Какая приятная для чтения конструкция, однако

Comment: Не понял я как на хэшкоде экранируются слэши. Вчера сначала съело половину, я удвоил, сегодня показывается удвоенное. В общем работает когда слева 4 палки, справа 8 палок.

Comment: да я заметил,вчера в этом ответе было меньше палок =)

Answer (score 0):

Так пробовали:

```
path.replace("\\", "\\\\");
```

Comment: у меня тоже съел слеши